# Controller returns View with modified link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, view

I have a view which is a .cshtml file with a button that executes the function `submitForm()` when clicked.

```
function submitForm() {
    fetch(`#{REPLACE_URL}#`);
}
```

In my controller I have an endpoint that modifies the .cshtml and then returns the View, but it shows the default .cshtml, not the modified one.
What I'm trying to to is to modify the `#{REPLACE_URL}#` value with a proper url. I need to do it in runtime since this url is different between the environments.

```
public IActionResult ShowViewEndpoint(...)
{
    ...Modify the "#{REPLACE_URL}#" tag in the View...

    return View(builder.HtmlBody);
}
```

How could I show the modified View? Is there a better way to do it instead the one I'm trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JS function is in the .cshtml file, you can set the value using Razor:

```
function submitForm() {
    fetch(`@(Model.MyUrl)`);
}
```

That way you can pass the URL from the server to the frontend